# Pandas label encoding column with default label for invalid row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, categorical-data

For a data frame I replaced a set of items in a column with a range of values as follows:

```
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].replace(regex=['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX'], value=[1, 2, 3, 4,5])
```

The issue that I want to replace all the rest of elements in 'Borough' that not mentioned before with the value 0
also  I need to use regex because there are looks like data eg. 07 BRONX, I need it also to be replaced by 5 not 0

Comment: Can you show a dummy dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

I see you want to perform category encoding with some imposed order. I would recommend using `pd.Categorical` with `ordered=True`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Borough': ['QUEENS', 'BRONX', 'MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'INVALID']})
df

     Borough
0     QUEENS
1      BRONX
2  MANHATTAN
3   BROOKLYN
4    INVALID

keys = ['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX']
df['borough_num'] = pd.Categorical(
    df['Borough'], categories=keys, ordered=True).codes+1

df

     Borough  borough_num
0     QUEENS            3
1      BRONX            5
2  MANHATTAN            1
3   BROOKLYN            2
4    INVALID            0
```

`pd.Categorical` returns invalid strings as -1:

```
pd.Categorical(
         df['Borough'], categories=keys, ordered=True).codes      
array([ 2,  4,  0,  1, -1], dtype=int8)
```

This should be *much* faster than using `replace`, anyway, but for reference, you would do this with `replace` and a dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
d.update(dict(zip(keys, range(len(keys)))))
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].map(d)

df

     Borough  borough_num
0     QUEENS            2
1      BRONX            4
2  MANHATTAN            0
3   BROOKLYN            1
4    INVALID            0
```

Answer (score 2):

To replace all other values by 0, you can do:

```
# create maps
new_values = ['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX']
maps = dict(zip(new_values, [1]*len(new_values)))

# map the values
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].apply(lambda x: maps.get(x, 0))
```

Comment: It works using: maps = dict(zip(new_values, [1,2,3,4,5]))
but I want to use regex to replace all items looks like not only that exactly the same as ['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX']

Answer (score 2):

Data from cold using `map` with `fillna`, all the value not in the map `dict` will return `NaN`, then we just `fillna`

```
df.Borough.map(dict(zip(['QUEENS', 'BRONX'],[1,2]))).fillna(0).astype(int)
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    0
Name: Borough, dtype: int32
```

Comment: @coldspeed no worry man :-) happy to see many of us still active during the weekends offer solutions

Comment: Great it works but I need to use regex because there are looks like data eg. 07 BRONX, i need it also to be replaced by 5 not o

Comment: Please mention why you used map, dict, zip, astype(int), since I am new to python

Comment: @MostafaQasim That... wasn't even mentioned in the question. You should understand that details like this change the _entire_ dynamic of your question. Remember, we are unpaid volunteers, please respect our time by helping us make sure our answers solve your actual problem, not a watered down version of it.

Comment: sorry, I thought using regex in my code made it clear

Comment: @MostafaQasim I would suggest opening a new question with updated requirements as the answers will need to be radically different.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [np.where](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=np.where&oq=np.where&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j0l4.1791j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

Creating a dummy DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Borough': ['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX', 'TEST']})
df
    Borough
0   MANHATTAN
1   BROOKLYN
2   QUEENS
3   STATEN ISLAND
4   BRONX
5   TEST
```

Your Operation:

```
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].replace(regex=['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX'], value=[1, 2, 3, 4,5])
df

    Borough   borough_num
0   MANHATTAN       1
1   BROOKLYN        2 
2   QUEENS          3
3   STATEN ISLAND   4
4   BRONX           5
5   TEST           TEST
```

Replacing values of column Borough not in keys with 0 using np.where:

```
keys = ['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX']
df['Borough'] = np.where(~df['Borough'].isin(keys), 0 ,df['Borough'])
df

    Borough    borough_num
0   MANHATTAN       1
1   BROOKLYN        2
2   QUEENS          3
3   STATEN ISLAND   4
4   BRONX           5
5   0             TEST
```